# Event propagation upwards or downwards

Tags: android, event-propagation

When a button on the screen is clicked, how does the event unfold? Does it begin with the button which has the option of passing the event to its parent?

Or does the parent receive the event first and pass it on to its children until it reaches the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 models for event propagation:

- Event capturing: Downward
- Event bubbling: Upward

Refer [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link1)